# Getting the sum of a column based on column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I need to get the sum of columns based on the name of the column. Currently, I'm using an IF ELSE block to take care of it, but I'm hoping there is a more automatic method for getting this sort of thing done.

What works:

```
foreach (var day in bydates)
            {
                var bymile_bydate = bymile.Where(x => x.Date == day).ToList();

                foreach (var r in results)
                {
                    var name = r.name;
                    if (name.Equals("TotalIssues"))
                    {
                        r.data.Add(bymile_bydate.Sum(x => x.TotalIssues).Value);
                    }
                    else if (name.Equals("TotalCritical"))
                    {
                        r.data.Add(bymile_bydate.Sum(x => x.TotalCritical).Value);
                    }
                }
            }
```

How I'd like to get it working:

```
        foreach (var day in bydates)
        {
            var bymile_bydate = bymile.Where(x => x.Date == day).ToList();

            foreach (var r in results)
            {
                r.data.Add(bymile_bydate.Sum(x=> x.(r.name)).Value);
            }
        }
```

So anyway way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# doesn't have good support for accessing members whose names aren't known at compile time. What I'll often do in this situation is have a dictionary of names to delegates that return the properties:

```
// assuming your objects are of type ClassX and your properties are decimals
static Dictionary<string, Func<ClassX, decimal>> PropertyLookup = 
    new Dictionary<string, Func<ClassX, decimal>>
    { { "TotalIssues", x => x.TotalIssues },
      { "TotalCritical", x => x.TotalCritical },
    };

foreach (var day in bydates)
{
    var bymile_bydate = bymile.Where(x => x.Date == day).ToList();

    foreach (var r in results)
    {
        var name = r.name;
        r.data.Add(bymile_bydate.Sum(PropertyLookup[name]).Value);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to have to define the property names ahead of time, you can use reflection to get the delegates. Here's an implementation that caches the delegates in a dictionary like the previous solution:

```
// assuming your objects are of type ClassX and your properties are decimals
static Dictionary<string, Func<ClassX, decimal>> PropertyLookup = 
    new Dictionary<string, Func<ClassX, decimal>>();

foreach (var day in bydates)
{
    var bymile_bydate = bymile.Where(x => x.Date == day).ToList();

    foreach (var r in results)
    {
        var name = r.name;
        if (!PropertyLookup.ContainsKey(name))
            PropertyLookup[name] = (Func<ClassX, decimal>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                typeof(Func<ClassX, decimal>),
                typeof(ClassX).GetProperty(name).GetGetMethod());
        r.data.Add(bymile_bydate.Sum(PropertyLookup[name]).Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to create the dictionary ahead of time, I've added a method that uses Reflection that's just as fast.

Answer (score 0):

Without reflection, you can't refer to the property name by a string value. And reflection would be a poor choice here. I'd recommend creating a property on the class that contains your totals that does the following:

```
public int? RelevantTotal
{
    get
    {
        switch (this.name)
        {
            case "TotalIssues":
                return this.TotalIssues;
            case "TotalCritical":
                return this.TotalCritical;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The when you loop through the results, call that property instead:

```
foreach (var day in bydates)
{
    var bymile_bydate = bymile.Where(x => x.Date == day).ToList();

    foreach (var r in results)
    {
        r.data.Add(bymile_bydate.Sum(x => r.RelevantTotal).Value);
    }
}
```